# Is there a brief way to create a reverse mapping given a function and a set of arguments?

Tags: java, java-8

Say we have a pure method that maps X to Y:

```
public abstract Y map(X x);
```

Is there any short way to create a reverse mapping from functions to sets of arguments that map to those functions? That is, to create a `Map<Y, Set<X>>` from a `Set<X>`. By short I mean a library solution that is briefer than the straight-forward way:

```
public Map<Y, Set<X>> reverseMapping(Set<X> arguments) {
    Map<Y, Set<X>> answer = new HashMap<>();
    arguments.forEach(x->{
        Y y = map(x);
        if (!answer.containsKey(y)) {
            answer.put(y, new HashSet<>());
        }
        answer.get(y).put(x);
    });
    return answer;
}
```

There are a lot of functional programming features added in Java 8, I thought there might be the one I need.

Comment: Note that even your manual collecting code can be improved using the Java 8 API `arguments.forEach(x-> answer.computeIfAbsent(map(x), key->new HashSet<>()).add(x) );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a straight-forward solution for this kind of task, [`Collectors.groupingBy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-). While the single-argument version produces a `Map<Y,List<X>`, you can [combine it with another `Collector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) to produce `Set`s

```
public Map<Y, Set<X>> reverseMapping(Set<X> arguments) {
    return arguments.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(this::map, Collectors.toSet()));
}
public abstract Y map(X x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always provide a `Function` as parameter as well, then the programming model will be nice.

```
public <X, Y> Map<Y, Set<X>> reverseMapping(Set<X> arguments, Function<X, Y> fn) {
    return arguments.stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                            fn, // The "map" invocation
                            Collectors.toSet()));
}

@Test
public void testFn() {
    final Set<String> cities = 
        Stream.of("NYC", "Los Angeles", "San Fransisco")
              .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    final Map<String, Set<String>> reversed = 
        reverseMapping(cities, city -> mapState(city));

    System.out.println(reversed); // -> {NY=[NYC], California=[San Fransisco, Los Angeles]}

}

// This is one version of a "map"-method as provided by the OP
private String mapState(String city) {
    switch (city) {
        case "NYC":
            return "NY";
        case "Los Angeles":
        case "San Fransisco":
            return "California";
    }
    return "Unknown";
}
```

Basically, you can provide your own *map*-method as a lambda.